# Quick Finding Relative Max Question

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

So, I was studying for a test and came across the following question:

"Let $$g(x)$$ be the function by $g(x)= \int_0^x (\frac{-3}{4}+t+cos(\frac{pi}{4}*t^2+t))$ for $0<x<4$. At what value of $x$ does $g$ attain a relative maximum?"

MathJax doesn't seem to wanna work on my computer, so here's a screenshot of the prompt as well:

[image]

I'm a bit confused on how I'd go about tackling something like this, would it involve converting the integral into terms of $x$? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You attain a relative maximum or minimum in an open subset (here $(0, 4)$) when the first derivative is zero. So write down $g'(x) = 0$ and solve it. If you are in trouble with the derivation of $g$, look at the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental theorem of calculus "says" that
$$g(x)=\int_0^x f(t) \, dt \implies g'(x)=f(x)$$ So, you first need to find the zero('s) of
$$g'(x)=-\frac{3}{4}+x+\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}x^2+x\right)$$ This is a transcendental equation which, by definition, will not show analytical solutions. As a consequence, some numerical methods will be required and then a reasonable starting guess.

If you plot the function, there is a root which is very close to $x=1.0$ and another close to $x=1.6$

Now, you are ready for Newton method which will generate the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.000000 \\
 1 & 1.024501 \\
 2 & 1.024508
\end{array}
\right)$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.600000 \\
 1 & 1.616232 \\
 2 & 1.615677
\end{array}
\right)$$
One of them will be a maximum and the other will be a minimum.